# Leg rig that transfroms between human form and digitigrade form

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, shape-keys

I’m trying to make a character that transforms from a human form to a more feral from, I started by making a human leg mesh that can swap between 2 states, Human and Digitigrade, to accomplish this effect I made a shape key that animates the mesh but now I want it rigged with armature but don’t really know of any way to make it change between the 2 states whilst still be a functional leg in both states[image]

the linked images is not parented to the mesh

Comment: I'm not sure how useful this could be, but one idea would be having a bone system similar to a IK>FK slider, to switch the control bones between the digitgrade legs, and the plantigrade legs. Here's a timestamped video that hopefully better shows what I'm trying to explain: [Unity/VRChat] IK adapter for digitigrade legs:
https://youtu.be/OlvmiBkoLQM?t=150 The video shows A character running with two different inter-changable leg rigs to show the differences in a digitgrade run, and a plantigrade run, on one model. Hope it helps, and good luck! If you make any discoveries please let me know, as